# Reading the number of rows inserted from another ongoing transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a transaction which is along the lines of

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO Table2 WITH(TABLOCK)
   SELECT BLAH 
   FROM Table

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

This transaction can take up to an hour to complete.

I'd like to run a query a bit like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2
```

at regular intervals on a totally different thread which could report how many rows have been inserted so far.

Is this possible? Is there some way to query for a count of rows which are not committed?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a WITH (NOLOCK) hint to your query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WITH (NOLOCK);
```

Take a baseline count before you begin your transaction, then subtract that value from the current number to get the number of newly inserted rows.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.  It returns zero, in spite of the main query running for 10 minutes.  I know the query works fine.  Maybe there's another way?

Comment: @Boomerangertanger: no, this is correct. Your query likely did not insert anything during those 10 minutes. If you never did a performance analysis of the query you can't know what is doing when. Perhaps it spends 59 minutes in the SELECT and 1 minute at the end in the INSERT part. Or perhaps it just sits there idle blocked by another transaction.

Comment: ok, fair enough. I'm finding that this simple stored proc takes 10 mins on my local machine and over an hour on SQL Azure with the same quantity of data.